# Fill data controls on ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

I am attempting to get the data my connectionstring pulls in my C# class's to the appropriate data controls on my website. I have looked online how to go about doing this but no results. I figured it would be easy like C# and you just reference the control you want to fill in the .Net page. Any suggestions on how to get my data into my controls? I have posted my c# code to get the data.

load method:

```
public void load()
{
    var sqlString = new StringBuilder();
    sqlString.Append("SELECT CaseNum6, CaseNum9, Group, Completion ");
    sqlString.Append("FROM WorkOrder ");
    sqlString.Append("WHERE Group = 1 OR Group = 2 ");
    sqlString.Append("AND Completion = 0 ");

    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlConnection dbConn = DBHelper.getConnection();
    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@CaseNum6", CaseNum6 )};

    try
    {
        reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), parameters);
        if (reader != null)
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                CaseNum6 = (int)reader["CaseNum6"];
                CaseNum9 = (int)reader["CaseNum9"];
                Group = (int)reader["Group"];
                Completion = (bool)reader["Completion"];
             }
             else
                throw new Exception("No record returned");
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
            dbConn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

DBHelper:

```
class DBHelper
{
    private DBHelper() { }

    public static SqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public static SqlConnection getFRESHConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FRESHConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public static SqlDataReader executeQuery(SqlConnection dbConn, string sqlString, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                dbConn.Open();
            cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sqlString;
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls use var at the left side.

Comment: @ClarkKent var on the left side?

Comment: i.e.   StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder(); replace with   var sqlString = new StringBuilder();

Comment: Ah ok why would you use that over my current method?

Comment: not getting what you want

Comment: Where are you assigning the data to the controls? - Please add the relevant code.  The sample seems to load data form db and assign to variaables/properties. What is the issue?

Comment: @donstack I'm still learning here and that does not tell me anything about the difference in the two.

Comment: Is Load() a method in your code-behind? You are assigning to CaseNum6, CaseNum9, Group, and Completion, but i don't know what they are. Is your reader returning data?

Comment: have you tried txtGroup.Text = (int)reader["Group"]; where txtGroup is Control name and Text is its property. http://asp.net-informations.com/data-providers/files/asp-datareader-default.aspx.cs.htm

Comment: @Kami that is the issue I don't know how to assign the data to the controls.

Comment: @ChrisHardie yes Load() is a method behind. They are db values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not have the right file extension for background coding.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly is the issue.  But to give an overview of how to add values to controls.

Drop a control from the toolbox into the web page(.aspx).

You will now be able to reference it in the code behind, and simply use something like

```
TextBox1.Text = "Hello World";     // TextBox1 is the id of the control
```

See more on MSDN docs
[Get and Set values on Textboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts3ffwhk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)